# Airflow reset connection (clear cache)

Tags: amazon-web-services, airflow, mwaa

I'm running Airflow locally and using AWS credentials (Environment variables) which get expired after some time and I wish to reset the connections as the new variables are not getting picked up and it keeps failing with access denied error. I was wondering if there is a way to force airflow to delete the cached credentials (if these are being cached).